# Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Cannot create an instance of unrecognized alias: widget.blogpanel

Tags: sencha-touch-2

i am new to sencha touch 2. while i was trying to instantiate after creating a blog view by following instructions from a tutorial.this error 
"Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Cannot create an instance of unrecognized alias: widget.blogpanel" appeared;

the code of blog.js is given below:

```
Ext.define('GS.view.blog',{
    extend:'Ext.navigation.View',
```

xtype: 'blog',

config:{
    title: 'Blog',
    iconCls: 'star',

    items:
    {
        xtype:'list',
        itemTpl:'{title}',
        store:
        {   
            autoLoad: true,
            fields:['title','author','content'],

            proxy:
            {
                type:'jsonp',
                url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/SenchaBlog',

                reader:
                {
                    type:'json',
                    rootProperty:'responseData.feed.entries',
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

});

Answer (score 1):

You need to check in the Ext.application.views to see if your class has been added

Answer (score 0):

This is relative to this one [Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Cannot create an instance of unrecognized alias: widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762338/uncaught-error-ext-createbyalias-cannot-create-an-instance-of-unrecognized-al).

You need to check the Ext.Application's "views" array

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @GabrielMongeon I am very new using stackoverflow so good tip the next time I go to do that