# Errors in the build when using sencha app build

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I have a simple universal app, which works just fine when tested using

`sencha app watch`

However, when i prepared a production/testing build version using

`sencha app build testing/production`

and tested it on a webserver, the errors started to come.

For example, the modern toolkit version has a form with **passwordfield** within and the error whown during the view instantiation is:

`Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: widget.passwordfield`

Alternatively, the classic toolkit version has a simple container with **layout: 'center'** and the error here is:

`Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: layout.center`

All this is very annoying, because it works just fine on sencha app watch.

Any ideas how to investigate this?

I'm pretty sure it is related to some sencha cmd configurations, but i have no way to find out where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Try to use alias:'widget.x' and make sure that the file is included also Just try to add them to requires of your main view.
Whenever you are creating a instance of an object using xtype within an items array, that same class must have the fully qualified name of the class that defines that xtype.

This one might help you, refer this link:

[Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Cannot create an instance of unrecognized alias: widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762338/uncaught-error-ext-createbyalias-cannot-create-an-instance-of-unrecognized-al)

2.This is because you are using layout:'center' , without adding the layout to the requires section.'Ext.layout.container.Center' to your requires section and run the appplication.

```
requires:[
  'Ext.layout.container.Center'
]
```

Refer this link:

[Build the application: Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: layout.center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43475228/build-the-application-error-ext-createbyalias-unrecognized-alias-layout-cen)

Comment: Yeah, the requires array was the missing part. The problem is that things are working fine when using sencha app watch during the development phase (without the need to require anything besides the classes within the app's namespace) and are failing on the build. Which simply raises confusion. Another thing to consider is the script load order, as mentioned here: (https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.5.1/guides/microloader.html)